# I have Matlab R2015b installed on Mac OS X 10.11.6 and installed Xcode 7.0.1 But libsvm-3.21 would not compile

Tags: macos, matlab, xcode7, libsvm

I have Matlab R2015b installed, and upgraded to Mac OS X 10.11.6 and installed Xcode version 7.0.1 But libsvm-3.21 would not compile. The following error occurs:-  /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/mex CC="c++" CXX="c++" CFLAGS="-Wall -Wconversion -O3 -fPIC -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/extern/include -I.." CXXFLAGS="-Wall -Wconversion -O3 -fPIC -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/extern/include -I.." -largeArrayDims svmpredict.c ../svm.o svm_model_matlab.o No supported compiler or SDK was found. For options, visit http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015b/maci64.html. make: * [svmpredict.mexmaci64] Error 255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you followed the supplied link? Under the Mac OS section there appears to be further setup required.

[See this link for more details](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/246507-why-can-t-mex-find-a-supported-compiler-in-matlab-r2015b-after-i-upgraded-to-xcode-7-0#answer_194526)